# Get full resource usage VMWare VCloud API

Tags: python, vmware, vcloud-director-rest-api

We are using a VDC that allows us to over-commit CPU resources and we would like to monitor how much we are using (the information is not provided to us). They have given us access to the VMWare VCloud API and I am using the python script [here](https://docs.ukcloud.com/articles/vmware/vmw-how-interact-vcd-api-powershell.html) along with the following code to get the CPU usage (in mHz) of all the VMs:

```
new_vcloud_login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")

# demo query, get all VMs and print them to screen
vms = get_vcloud_request("query?type=vm&fields=name&pageSize=1000").decode('utf-8')
vm_ids = re.findall('"https://mycloud.syd.zettagrid.com/api/vApp/(vm-.*?)"', vms)

total = 0

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CurrentUsageSpec xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5">
   <MetricPattern>cpu.usagemhz.average</MetricPattern>
</CurrentUsageSpec>"""

for id in vm_ids:
    metric_data = get_vcloud_request("vApp/" + id + "/metrics/current", xml).decode('utf-8')
    cpu = re.findall('.*"cpu.usagemhz.average".*value="(.*?)".*', metric_data)

    total += float(cpu[0])

print(total)
```

The issue with this is that it's very slow and quickly eats away at the API limits because it's having to send a request for each VM. Is there an VMWare VCloud API function that would provide this information in a single request? I tried using [this](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/1159/vmware-cloud-director/doc/doc/types/OrgVdcRollupType.html) all the CPU related data was `0`.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don`t need to gather all used CPU from every VM, just get CPU from organization VDC ?
I think this cant help you:

```
   GET /vdc/{id}
```

[Get VDC Information](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/7a028e78-bd37-4a6a-8298-9c26c7eeb9aa/09142237-dd46-4dee-8326-e07212fb63a8/doc/doc/operations/GET-Vdc.html)

Comment: I was able to get the VDC data, however, the CPU shows `<Used>0</Used>` in the response. It is definitely not using no CPU resources, and I have validated that I'm using the correct VDC ID.

Comment: THis is my api call result:  "computeCapacity": {
        "otherAttributes": {},
        "cpu": {
            "otherAttributes": {},
            "units": "MHz",
            "allocated": 0,
            "limit": 0,
            "reserved": 0,
            "used": 2000,
            "reservationUsed": 1000,
            "vCloudExtension": []
        },
        ...
    }, Strange that you get 0. Maybe there is no running VM on current VDC?

Comment: There are definitely VMs on that VDC and it also seems to be showing the correct memory used but not CPU.